# Making a point at forehead use kinect c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect, tracking

I want to make a point at my forehead by using sample "Face Tracking Basics WPF" from Kinect for Windows Developers Toolkit v1.7.0. Did anyone knows ?

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Exchange network. You’ll have a much better chance of getting good answers if your question is clearer, shows the research you’ve done, what you’ve tried, what errors you got, etc. Be sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: finally i made it succes. this is the step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i made it succes. this is the step.
open FaceTrackingViewer.xaml

replace "DrawFaceModel" with :

```
public void DrawFaceModel(DrawingContext drawingContext)
        {
            if (!this.lastFaceTrackSucceeded || this.skeletonTrackingState != SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
            {
                return;
            }

            var faceModelPts = new List<Point>();
            var faceModel = new List<FaceModelTriangle>();
            //double[] xarray;
            //double[] yarray;

            for (int i = 0; i < this.facePoints.Count; i++)
            {
                faceModelPts.Add(new Point(this.facePoints[i].X + 0.5f, this.facePoints[i].Y + 0.5f));
                //xarray[i] = this.facePoints[i].X;
                //yarray[i] = this.facePoints[i].Y;
            }

           // double xpos21 = this.facePoints[21].X;
            //double xpos21 = this.facePoints[21].X;
            //Bikin Titik di jidat


            foreach (var t in faceTriangles)
            {
                var triangle = new FaceModelTriangle();
                triangle.P1 = faceModelPts[t.First];
                triangle.P2 = faceModelPts[t.Second];
                triangle.P3 = faceModelPts[t.Third];
                faceModel.Add(triangle);
            }

           // ColorImagePoint j1p = faceModelPts.Add(new Point(this.facePoints[1].X + 0.5f, this.facePoints[1].Y + 0.5f));
           // ColorImagePoint j1p = myKinect.MapSkeletonPointToColor(faceModelPts[1].Position, ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30);



            //var faceModelGroup = new GeometryGroup();
            //for (int i = 0; i < faceModel.Count; i++)
            //{
            //    var faceTriangle = new GeometryGroup();
            //    faceTriangle.Children.Add(new LineGeometry(faceModel[i].P1, faceModel[i].P2));
            //    faceTriangle.Children.Add(new LineGeometry(faceModel[i].P2, faceModel[i].P3));
            //    faceTriangle.Children.Add(new LineGeometry(faceModel[i].P3, faceModel[i].P1));
            //    faceModelGroup.Children.Add(faceTriangle);
            //}

            var faceModelGroup = new GeometryGroup();
            //for (int i = 0; i < faceModel.Count; i++)
            //{
                var faceTriangle = new GeometryGroup();
                faceTriangle.Children.Add(new LineGeometry(faceModel[1].P1, faceModel[1].P2));
                faceTriangle.Children.Add(new LineGeometry(faceModel[1].P2, faceModel[1].P3));
                faceTriangle.Children.Add(new LineGeometry(faceModel[1].P3, faceModel[1].P1));

                faceModelGroup.Children.Add(faceTriangle);
            //}
                //((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).jidat1.Content = Math.Round(facePoints[1].X,3);
                //((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).jidat2.Content = Math.Round(facePoints[1].Y,3);

           drawingContext.DrawGeometry(Brushes.LightYellow, new Pen(Brushes.LightYellow, 1.0), faceModelGroup);
           //drawingContext.DrawEllipse(Brushes.LightYellow, new Pen(Brushes.LightYellow, 1.0), faceModelPts[1]);


         }
```

you will get a triangle at your face